# How to set jms header for message that is consumed via spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

In order for message to move to undelivered queue in case of maxRelivery attempts, the tibco broker expect to set a jms property `JMS_TIBCO_PRESERVE_UNDELIVERED` to `true`. I am not sure how to set this property after the message is consumed.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                .destination(sourceQueue)
                .configureListenerContainer(spec -> {
                    spec.sessionTransacted(false);
                    spec.sessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                })
               .handle(someservice).get();
```

Comment: I would guess that it's a producer property, not a consumer property.

Comment: ok let me try setting while publishing the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property is for a JMS producer.

That's not too hard to use an `.enrichHeaders()` to set this value into the headers before sending a message into the `.handle(Jms.outboundAdapter())`.

See more info here: https://haritibcoblog.com/2017/04/03/tibco-ems-properties-of-queues-and-topics-where-tuning-can-be-done/

Comment: Thanks for the link, it worked by setting the header while publishing the message.

Comment: May be useful for others, If the there is an errorHandler or idempotent receiver configured the message is consumed and not sent to undelivered queue after 2 attempts